# How to position rect elements about the x-axis in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning to use D3.js, and although the height of my rects on the y axis coincides with the value of the axis, they go to the bottom of my SVG, instead of positioning themselves on the x axis:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EObyA.png)

I share the snippet of my code:

```
let data = {
    "month": "Enero",
    "expenses": [{
        "id": 1,
        "category": "Comida",
        "total": 1500
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": "Vicio",
        "total": 2000
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "category": "Ropa",
        "total": 1000
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "Alquiler",
        "total": 2100
    }]
}

let width = 800;
let height = 1000;
let padding = 50;
let xScale;
let yScale;

let gastos = data.expenses;
console.log(gastos)

let generateScale = () => {
    yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([d3.max(gastos, (item) => { return item["total"] + 500 }), d3.min(gastos, (item) => { return item["total"] - 500 })]).range([padding, height - padding]);

    xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([d3.min(gastos, (item) => { return item["id"] - 1 }), d3.max(gastos, (item) => { return item["id"] + 1 })]).range([padding, width - padding]);
}
let svg = d3.select('#canvas')
    .attr('width', 800)
    .attr('height', 1000)

let drawRect = () => {
    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(gastos)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return yScale(d['total']);
        })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
            return d['total'];
        })
        .attr('x', (item) => {
            return xScale(item['id']);
        })
        .attr('width', 40)
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')

}

let generateAxes = () => {
    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)

    svg.append('g')
        .call(xAxis)
        .attr('id', 'x-axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - padding) + ')')

    svg.append('g')
        .call(yAxis)
        .attr('id', 'y-axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ', 0)')
}
generateScale()
generateAxes()
drawRect()
```

I tried modifying the 'height' and 'y' attribute but did not get the expected results.

```
.attr('y', function (d) {
            return yScale(d['total']);
          })          
.attr('height', function (d) {
            return d['total'];
          })
```

Removing the scale, subtracting the height, etc.

Comment: Your question won't probably be reopened, next time just ask a new question in English. Anyway, you have to subtract the zero position for the height: `.attr('y', function (d) { return yScale.range()[1] - yScale(d['total']);})`.

Comment: Gerardo, I will ask the question again in English. I tried the solution that you tell me but the graph does not look as expected, in any case I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this while trying to fix the same issue.

I fixed it by doing:

```
.attr("height", d => height - yScale([d])-padding)
```